# jQuery Fade-in and Out when click Again

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

This is what i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("#menu").click(function () {
        jQuery("#menu-open").slideDown("slow");
      });
    });
</script>
```

How to automatically close the menu when the user clicks again?

Comment: Use `slideToggle` i.e `jQuery("#menu-open").slideToggle("slow");` or if you mean fade then use `fadeToggle` instead of `slideToggle`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $("#menu").click(function () {
      if(!$("#menu-open").is(":visible")){
          $("#menu-open").slideDown("slow");
      } else {
          $("#menu-open").slideUp("slow");
      }

  });
});
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/9FehL/2/

Comment: Your the man. i kind of knew it have to do something with else cause i study objective-C and C programming. but anyway thank you so much bro.

Comment: DO you also know how to set the duration of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $("#menu").click(function () {
        $("#menu-open").fadetoggle();
      });
    });
</script>
```

use this, but im not use if you want it to fade or slide? since you ask for fadein but you use slide

You can also use .slidetoggle();

If you want to read more about fadetoggle, read this [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)